# There is already an object named '#dirs' in the database error message even though I'm checking and dropping the temp table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not sure why I keep getting the object already exists message if I'm doing the check whether the object exists and I'm dropping it if it does. Anyone have any clues?

Error message:

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spCreateDirectoryStructure, Line 54
There is already an object named '#dirs' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spCreateDirectoryStructure, Line 74
There is already an object named '#dirs' in the database.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateDirectoryStructure
AS 
       BEGIN
             SET NOCOUNT ON;

             DECLARE @year CHAR(4)
             DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2)
             DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2)
             DECLARE @root VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @dir VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @yearDir VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @monthDir VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @dayDir VARCHAR(200)

             SET @root = 'C:\Test\'
             SET @year = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
             SET @month = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
             SET @day = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())
             SET @yearDir = @root + @year + '\'
             SET @monthDir = @root + @year + '\' + @month + '\'
             SET @dayDir = @root + @year + '\' + @month + '\' + @day + '\'

            -- check root folder for year folder
             IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#dirs') IS NOT NULL 
                BEGIN 
                      DROP TABLE #dirs
                END

             CREATE TABLE #dirs (Directory VARCHAR(200))

             INSERT INTO #dirs
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @root


             IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Directory
                             FROM   #dirs
                             WHERE  Directory = @year ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @yearDir

            -- **********************************************
            -- check year folder for month folder

             IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#dirs') IS NOT NULL 
                BEGIN
                      DROP TABLE #dirs
                END
             CREATE TABLE #dirs (Directory VARCHAR(200))

             INSERT INTO #dirs
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @yearDir


             IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Directory
                             FROM   #dirs
                             WHERE  Directory = @month ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @monthDir

            -- **********************************************
            -- check month folder for day folder

             IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#dirs') IS NOT NULL 
                BEGIN
                      DROP TABLE #dirs
                END
             CREATE TABLE #dirs (Directory VARCHAR(200))

             INSERT INTO #dirs
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @monthDir


             IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Directory
                             FROM   #dirs
                             WHERE  Directory = @day ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @dayDir
       END
GO
```

Comment: Add a comment in next to your drop statement  (`PRINT '#dirs dropped'`) and check that it is happening as you expect.  The temp tables often ahve a unique suffix added which can mess up querying their meta data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #dirs exists when the stored procedure is compiled.

Just remove the table and then you can create the stored procedure.

Since you are creating the table anyway, consider declaring it as a local variable:

```
declare @dirs table (directory varchar(200))
```

The local variable will be removed automatically when it goes out of scope (when the stored procedure exits).  Then you don't have to worry about cleaning up the temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have

```
         CREATE TABLE #dirs (Directory VARCHAR(200))
```

**THRICE**.  When parsing the TSQL batch, SQL Server sees the 2nd one and statically determines it will exist on the 2nd time around.

My advise is not to test for it, create it once (at the very top) and instead TRUNCATE to clear it before each use.  FYI, even if you had a #dirs in the session calling this SP, another one will be created within the context of the SP and it will go out of scope at the end of the SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateDirectoryStructure
AS 
             DECLARE @year CHAR(4)
             DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2)
             DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2)
             DECLARE @root VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @dir VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @yearDir VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @monthDir VARCHAR(200)
             DECLARE @dayDir VARCHAR(200)

             SET @root = 'C:\Test\'
             SET @year = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
             SET @month = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
             SET @day = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())
             SET @yearDir = @root + @year + '\'
             SET @monthDir = @root + @year + '\' + @month + '\'
             SET @dayDir = @root + @year + '\' + @month + '\' + @day + '\'

             CREATE TABLE #dirs (Directory VARCHAR(200))

             INSERT INTO #dirs
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @root


             IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Directory
                             FROM   #dirs
                             WHERE  Directory = @year ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @yearDir

            -- **********************************************
            -- check year folder for month folder

             TRUNCATE TABLE #dirs
             INSERT INTO #dirs
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @yearDir


             IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Directory
                             FROM   #dirs
                             WHERE  Directory = @month ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @monthDir

            -- **********************************************
            -- check month folder for day folder

             TRUNCATE TABLE #dirs
             INSERT INTO #dirs
                    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 
                        @monthDir


             IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Directory
                             FROM   #dirs
                             WHERE  Directory = @day ) 
                EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 
                    @dayDir
GO
```