# How do I force a drop temp table command to fully drop the table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I'm working on a script, just experimenting and developing. A lot of what I do involves temp tables, where I will `select ... into #SomeTable from ...`, at least in the initial experimentation/early dev stage.

Then I'll look at the results, make some changes, and go again. But to make things a little easier on myself, I also have a `drop table if exists #SomeTable`, so I can just rerun the code. So far so good. But, if I add a column to the temp table and then try to access it, I get the error `Invalid column name 'newColumn'`. I can avoid the error by executing JUST the drop statement, and then executing the whole script, but I would rather not have to do that. As I understand it, there is some caching of temp tables that goes on, and I wonder if that's the culprit. In any case, is there any way to fix this?

Edit: Here is a short script demonstrating the problem. Run the script, then uncomment both comments and run it again:

```
drop table if exists #DemoTable
select column1 = '1'
      ,column2 = '2'
--      ,column3 = '3'
into #DemoTable

select column1
      ,column2
--      ,column3
from #DemoTable
```

Comment: Can you show the script or the query?

Comment: Please add a script to a question so we can reproduce this error. Drop table fully drops the table, there is no caching.

Comment: Yes, this is strange so we need the query. Maybe a collation changes the column name to something close but different? If you `select *` do you see the new column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is already an object named '#dirs' in the database error message even though I'm checking and dropping the temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767377/there-is-already-an-object-named-dirs-in-the-database-error-message-even-thou) If you have the same name twice in a batch then you are going to get errors

Comment: @George select * does indeed show the new column, which, maybe points to some parser optimization/laziness? I'm using SSMS if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS you can just add a `GO` statement to separate the code in 2 batches.
This way the `drop` is executed before the 2nd part of the script is checked for errors.

```
drop table if exists #DemoTable
GO

select column1 = '1'
      ,column2 = '2'
--      ,column3 = '3'
into #DemoTable

select column1
      ,column2
--      ,column3
from #DemoTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to follow the steps mentioned in the question.

Please find the following query samples using Northwind Database.
Added a new column to the temp table and also updated it sucessfully.

```
-- Create the temporary table #temp_Employees from a physical table called 'Employee' in schema 'dbo' in database 'Northwind'
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName , BirthDate
INTO #temp_Employees
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Employees]

-- SELECT data from temptable '[#temp_Employees]' 
SELECT * FROM #temp_Employees;

-- Add a new column '[City]' to table '[#temp_Employees]' 
ALTER TABLE #temp_Employees 
    ADD [City] NVARCHAR(15)  NULL
GO

-- SELECT data from temptable '[#temp_Employees]' 
SELECT * FROM #temp_Employees;

-- UPDATE the new column '[City]' in the table '[#temp_Employees]' 
UPDATE T
SET  T.[City]=E.[City]
FROM #temp_Employees T INNER JOIN [Northwind].[dbo].[Employees] E ON T.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID;

-- SELECT data from temptable '[#temp_Employees]' 
SELECT * FROM #temp_Employees;

-- Drop the temptable if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#temp_Employees', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_Employees;
GO

-- SELECT data from temptable '[#temp_Employees]' 
SELECT * FROM #temp_Employees;
```

Thank you.